# A complex analysis problem---concerning distance

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_i, i=1,2,\cdots,n$ be $n$ points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_i|>1$. Prove that there exists at least one $z_0$ satisfying $|z_0|=1$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n |z_i-z_0|>1$.

I do not have any idea after two days of thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $$p(z) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (z_i - z)$$

Then $|p(0)| > 1$, and the maximum modulus principle can be used.

Comment: @DavidHolden Whoops, yes. Thanks!

Comment: damned typos! but an impeccable answer to the question.